# AWS DynamoDB response size different between CLI and Node SDK

Tags: pagination, secondary-indexes, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to optimize my query to dynamodb to return all matching items. From the cli I can query the table and it returns all 303 items.

CLI Request:

> aws dynamodb query --table-name my-table --index-name "myGsi" --key-condition-expression 'myId=:someId' --expression-attribute-values  '{":someId":{"S":"86c10962-6444-4f09-8f6c-dc6b30abac25"}}'
> Response:

```
{
    "Items": [
         { ... },
         { ... }
     ],
    "Count": 303,
    "ScannedCount": 303,
    "ConsumedCapacity": null
}
```

The problem is that when I try to recreate that query in my Typescript application, I only get ~60 items in the response (not always consistent).

Code:

```
const params: DocumentClient.QueryInput = {
  TableName: 'my-table',
  IndexName: 'myGsi',
  KeyConditionExpression: 'myId = :someId',
  ExpressionAttributeValues: {
    ':someId': '86c10962-6444-4f09-8f6c-dc6b30abac25',
  }
};
const result: DocumentClient.QueryOutput = await dynamoClient.query(params).promise();
```

However, the result here is much smaller, and I need to paginate:

```
{
    "Items": [
         { ... },
         { ... }
     ],
    "Count": 59,
    "ScannedCount": 59,
    "LastEvaluatedKey": "xyz"
}
```

Any ideas on how to get all/more of the content in a single request from the SDK? Why would the results be different than my CLI request?

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html):

> A single `Query` operation will read up to the maximum number of items set (if using the `Limit` parameter) **or a maximum of 1 MB** of data and **then apply** any filtering to the results using `FilterExpression`. If `LastEvaluatedKey` is present in the response, **you will need to paginate the result set**. For more information, see [Paginating the Results](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Query.html#Query.Pagination) in the Amazon DynamoDB Developer Guide.

Don't know if I can add something else to it. That's the expected behavior.

> Any ideas on how to get all/more of the content in a single request from the SDK?

Look's like it's impossible with the original library. Unless you fork it and hack it. But there're 2 other options:

- you can try to set the `Limit` to some insanely big value, and maybe it'll override the hardcoded 1 MB limit in the library. Don't know - haven't tried it.
- or you can use `aws dynamodb query` through `exec()` (or some similar `child_process`'s funcs) if you really need to.

In either case, be warned - it can cost you money. So maybe it's better to stick to pagination.

Comment: Yes, I understood the docs, and what you mentioned is current. However, I still don't understand why the results from the CLI would be different. Calling a child_process would work, but it is such a hack! Thank you for your feedback!

Comment: I imagine that's exactly because it's a hack - seems that this CLI is supposed to be used manually, so AWS doesn't care about protecting against overcharge. But, as I said, if you won't use pagination it can **unexpectedly** lead to a huge quota usage.